# what is poseAsClass in iphone ? i want some base example for this

Tags: iphone, cocoa

i want to run poseAsClass in iphone class . i try but can't find good example for this .

i know only that this is use for inherit class method in other class . means same name methods in two class and call particular method . i m right or wrong i dont know. i m confuse ...

i show this things in one of example but that example is not working .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+[NSObject poseAsClass:]` was deprecated in Mac OS X 10.5 and was never supported on iOS.  If it still works at all, then it's a fluke.  You should not use it.

Comment: if i want to use in os x then how can i use this ? i don't know anything about that . i know only about ios

Comment: @Heart PAL you'd only be able to use it if you're targeting Mac OS X 10.4 or lower.

Comment: ok i want to use same concept for mac os 10.6.2 or above versen that what i have to do ?